# Regular polygon with different height and width

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I want to create a polygon with Kinetic.js and I know the **width**, **height**, **rotation** and **number of points** for the polygon.

I thought this would be possible by using the RegularPolygon object, but for it I have to set a value for radius. A triangle would be created like this:

```
var hexagon = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
    x: stage.width()/2,
    y: stage.height()/2,
    sides: 3,
    radius: 70,
    fill: 'red',
});
```

See a similar polygon being created here:
http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-regular-polygon-tutorial/

The result would look something like this:

[image]

But what if I want to create a triangle of which the width should be twice the height? Looking something like this:

[image]

As far as I understand, this not possible by just adjusting the radius.

How can I achieve this for any polygon? Note that I don't know the values for the points to begin with (they could be calculated though). I think that scaleX and scaleY might be possible to use, but is it possible to achieve it in an easier way? I would like just to set width and height directly.

Comment: KineticJS polygons are regular polygons (all sides are equal length). Scaling a regular-triangle is awkward so your best solution might be to just draw a poly-line forming your triangles.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I can do this? How do I calculate the points knowing the width, height, rotation of the area, along with the number of points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KineticJS polygons are regular polygons (all sides are equal length).

Scaling a regular-polygon is awkward if you want to stroke the polygon because the stroke is also scaled and therefore the stroke deforms.

So your best solution might be to just draw a poly-line forming your triangles.

[image]

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: 350,
  height: 350
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var PI=Math.PI;
var PI2=PI*2;

scaledRegularPolygon(100,100,30,5,2,1,'red');

function scaledRegularPolygon(cx,cy,radius,sides,scaleX,scaleY,fill){
  var points=[];
  for(var i=0;i<sides;i++){
    var sweep=PI2/sides;
    var midbottom=PI/2;
    var rightbottom=midbottom-sweep/2;
    var start=rightbottom-sweep;
    var angle=start+sweep*i;
    var x=cx+radius*Math.cos(angle);
    var y=cy+radius*Math.sin(angle);
    x=cx+(x-cx)*scaleX;
    y=cy+(y-cy)*scaleY;
    points.push(x,y);
  }
  var poly=new Kinetic.Line({
    points:points,
    closed:true,
    fill:fill,
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth:4
  });
  layer.add(poly);
  layer.draw();
}
```

```css
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, much appreciated!

However, it doesn't really solves everything, as it only works for triangles and not polygons with any number of points. I'm not sure if to mark the answer as accepted.

I should be able to use that method to get forward though, just haven't started yet.

Comment: I see, so you need a generic regular polygon scaling algorithm.  I've edited may answer to show how to do that using trigonometry. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks!

In this case, is the radius the inner-radius or the circum-radius?

Comment: Also, it still doesn't truly solve my problem.

As I said I didn't have radius, scaleX and scaleY, so I need to calculate them before calling the funciton. I tried to calculate the radius based on width and height (width and height of a rectangle bounding box of the polygon), but I'm not getting it perfect. I'm not sure how to calculate scaleX and scaleY either.

Answer (score 0):

`Kinetic.Transform` allows us to calculate the position of a point from a transform matrix by passing in  the point to `Kinetic.Transform.point()`. From the object you want to transform the points for, get its transform matrix with `Kinetic.Node.getAbsoluteTransform().copy()` (or `Kinetic.Node.getTransform().copy()`, whatever seems suitable for your purposes). Then we call `Kinetic.Transform.scale(2,2)` on the transform matrix to get a matrix with twice the scale. Then for each point, use `Kinetic.Transform.point()` to get its new position.